# How to compress 256^3 unique data points in order. Each data point is a value from 1 to 255

Tags: compression, language-agnostic, mit-scratch

I am trying to compress 256^3 datapoints into a 256 digit or less long string (using only base 10 numbers). I have already tried a few things which I will list below.

I have tried to switch between addition and subtraction between parentheses. for example: 255+(122-(32+(10-3))) but I don't know how to reverse it and get the original number back when just having the sum.

I do not know how else to compress that many data-points into a 256 or less digit string. (because in theory it should be possible because there are more total values in a 256 digit long string than there are values of my data points.)

I need a way to do this language agnostically.

Comment: What do you mean? 256 digit long string is less than 256 bytes (because there are less then 256 possibilities for each digit), but 256^3 datapoints is more than 16 megabytes.

Comment: should it not be more because it is base 10?

Comment: an ASCII string is base 256, because each symbol can be one of 256 possibilities. You may be confusing a byte with a bit: one bit is a 1 or a 0, but one byte contains 8 bits and has 256 states.

Comment: Is there any way to compress my datapoints (taking advantage of the fact that each one can only be from 1-255). I can't have any more digits because I am programing this on scratch and am trying to transfer this data through a cloud variable(which can only have 256 characters).

Comment: There is another way to think about it:
Each data point is a number between 1 and 256, so if it is more than 9 you already need at least 2 digits of your string to store it. But even if you could store one data point in one digit, you would need to have at least 16 million digits to store 16 million data points.

Comment: I think you are looking for some kind of compression algorithm. Do you really have 16M different block IDs? Or are some of them reused? Is there an ID for each possible coordinate or are those blocks sparse?

Answer (score 1):

Each of your data points is almost 1 byte (255 unique values instead of 256). If there are 16 million of data points (256^3) then there is 16 MB of data.

Your string has 256 digits from 0 to 9, so it can store 10^256 states, or around 106 bytes. So unless the values have some extreme dependencies between each other, there is no way to compress 16MB down to 106B

Comment: each of the values represents a specific block ID at a specific coordinate (X,Y,Z). If I could transfer the ID's in order then I would not need to transfer the coordinate for each block (which would take up far more data.) So is there any way to do this (or how many block ID's would I have to cut down to?

Comment: Take a step back and think what you are trying to do. You are trying to compress MILLIONS of values into a handful of digits (less than a thousand digits). 10 values per digit will not be enough.

Comment: is there any way to represent the data in 10 strings of 256 digits? (I can have up to 10 cloud variables in my project [problem is you can only update 1 variable per 0.1 seconds]. does having more room to work with allow it to work?)

Comment: No.............

Answer (score 0):

No. Just no.

To make clear how far away you are from being able to do what you want to do, assuming that all 255 values of each coordinate are equally likely, you are asking to store 134 *million* bits of information in 850 bits! In a comment you ask about ten 256-digit strings in which case you'll have 8500 bits to put it in. You're off by a factor of 160,000, or 16,000 with ten of them.

I can't imagine why you would think "because in theory it should be possible".